# passing dynamic values to query in java for binarystream

Tags: java, sql, dynamic, arrays

I am trying to pass values dynamically to PreparedStatement and insert record in DB as below and I am able to do it as below.

```
String fName="AA"; // this value changes
String lName="BB"  //this value changes 
String query="insert into person(first_name,last_name) values ('"+fName+"','"+lName+"')"
PreparedStatement ps= null;
ps== connection.prepareStatement(query); 
ps.executeUpdate();
```

But I have byteArray[] which I converted to ByteArrayInputStream ..this value I am not able to pass dynamically as above like fName and lName for my third colum photo which is Blob.

but if i do like ,

```
byte[] b =somebytesss...
ByteArrayInputStream bin=new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
String query="insert into person(first_name,last_name,photo) values (?,?,?)"
PreparedStatement ps= null;
ps.setString(1,"AA");
ps.setString(2,"BB");
ps.setBinaryStream(3,bin,bin.available());
ps== connection.prepareStatement(query); 
ps.executeUpdate();
```

this is also working.

**but I want to avoid this manual setting of the values.
I just want to pass dynamic query like my first case to preparestatement for bytearray[] also.**

Can anyone please let me know how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: `but I want to avoid this manual setting of the values` Why? If you're parsing user input, you should absolutely be using prepared statements. Maybe read up on SQL injection if you're not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the second example, creating a prepared statement with parameters is the preferred way to do that. It secures you against SQL injection. You should keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks all.But I have written one generic method for insert in DB.And I want to pass values to this generic method by building dynamic query . but in case of bytearray[] I am not able to do it. Any suggesions..

Comment: Really, you shouldn't. It would cause a great vulnerability in your application. Maybe read a bit about SQL Injection if you don't understand why. And by the way, you ARE building the query dynamically...?